# What are the hex outputs in a truffle migrate?

Tags: truffle

I am testing on accounts and addresses and I am trying to understand the hex outputs in truffle. I have this -

```
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing CA10...
  ... 0x7563df6c873b68c4337487146dd0ff438a7dd61bb44c7fe10b84d53a398af2ba
  CA10: 0xd2af90a472ab8ac41cad694c06fc60b0b72f54be
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x11c062f191b5627641f93030c496d3c9e3ce59bdd4da17802e4798a600782f71
Saving artifacts...
```

I understand that 0xd2af90a472ab8ac41cad694c06fc60b0b72f54be is the contract address. But I am unsure about the other numbers. Are these some kind of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the transaction hashes.

The first transaction is the deployment of the contract itself.

The second transaction is the update on truffle's Migration instance. It stores on-chain that migration step 2_deply_contracts has been executed.

Comment: Why two hashes for one contract?

Comment: I've extended the answer.